# Mysql query between and like query

Tags: mysql

I had a table in which dates are storing in datetime format like '2016-06-29 00:58:12'. I have to find the data between two dates but the problem is that i stored this with time also so how can i get the output ..

I tried

```
SELECT time_of_action FROM `trackvendoraction`  where time_of_action like '2016-06-29%'
union
SELECT time_of_action FROM `trackvendoraction`  where time_of_action like '2016-06-30%'
```

i this above query i got the data for two dates now i had to apply the between query . how can i do this ? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT time_of_action 
FROM `trackvendoraction`  
WHERE time_of_action BETWEEN '2016-06-29 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-30 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you column is a datetime you have to use the timepart as below:

```
SELECT time_of_action FROM `trackvendoraction`  where time_of_action between '2016-06-29 00:00:00' and '2016-06-30 23:59:59'
```